# BluetoothDevice.getName() is null

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I use the following receiver to get the surrounding bluetooth devices :

```
// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
            // object and its info from the Intent.
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String deviceName = device.getName();
            String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
            Log.d(TAG, "Device hardware adress : " + deviceHardwareAddress);

            if (deviceName != null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Device name : " + deviceName);
                if (deviceName.contains("GYDE")){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Stooping discovery : " + deviceName);

                    // Don't forget to unregister the ACTION_FOUND receiver.
                    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
                }
            }

        }
    }
};
```

I have 2 bluetooth devices in the area. I see their MAC Adress but they've got no names. I believe though they have names because :

1) I could see it when testing yesterday (nothing has been modified since then)

2) My phone can list their name after enabling bluetooth

3) I can actually see my phone name

Comment: Did you find the solution to the null name ?

Comment: I do not need it anymore. What I can tell you from memory though is that the discovery sometimes finishes before the names are fetched. I think there must be a way to keep the discovery running to update the name as soon as we have them. Good luck !